# How to get Java to display a newly generated image without having to restart the compiler

Tags: java

I have two buttons, 'resize' and 'display'. The first button resizes an image, while the other displays it. The image does get resized after clicking the resize button but it doesn't display the new-sized image right away, i have to restart Netbean for it to display the new image. Are there a way to do this without having to restart my netbean?

```
private String picture = "...test.png";
private String picture2 = "...test2.png";
private ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(picture); 
private ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(picture2);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==btn){
    File oldimage= new File(picture);
    BufferedImage buffimage = null;
    try {
        buffimage = ImageIO.read(oldimage);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Movie_Poster_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    BufferedImage resized = resize(buffimage, 500, 700);
    File newimage = new File(picture2);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(resized, "png", newimage);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Movie_Poster_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
    if(e.getSource()==btn2){
        lbl.setIcon(image2);
    }
    ;
```

Comment: Of course there's a way to do it, but we can't give you any specifics because you have not shown us anything about how the image is displayed in the first place.  But I do observe that your resizing code does *nothing* that I would expect to affect the program's UI.  Consider: how did you cause the original image to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing some information that I would need to give a 100% correct and full solution, but if I am assuming correctly you just want to put the resized image in the frame where you are displaying it.  It seems like your frame is a `JLabel` so the line you would want to add is:

```
lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resized));
```

So the full code would be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btn) {
        File oldimage = new File(picture);
        BufferedImage buffimage = null;
        try {
            buffimage = ImageIO.read(oldimage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Movie_Poster_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        BufferedImage resized = resize(buffimage, 500, 700);
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resized));
        File newimage = new File(picture2);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(resized, "png", newimage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Movie_Poster_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else if (e.getSource() == btn2) {
        lbl.setIcon(image2);
    }
}
```

***Happy Coding!***